# Print custom error message using manually created exception class

Tags: python, exception, custom-error-handling

I have a custom exception class as:

```py
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

And I am invoking it as follows:

```py
class over():

    def check():        
        col1 = 'ageminusone'
        col2 = 'Age'
        col3 = 'Flag'

        data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])


        df[col1] = df.loc[0,col2] - 1

        books = ['romance',  'fiction']

        try:
            regex_pattern = re.compile(r'fiction')  
            for book in books:
                match_object = re.search(regex_pattern, booke)
                print(match_object)

        except MyException:
            print("There was an error")
            raise MyException



a = over.check()
print(a)
```

I get only the traceback error in the log, not the custom message "There was an error" like so:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare.py", line 53, in <module>
    a = over.check()
  File "compare.py", line 41, in check
    match_object = re.search(regex_pattern, booke)
NameError: name 'booke' is not defined
```

How can I modify this code to print "There was an error" before the actual traceback?

Note: The ask is not to use the generic "Exception" like:

```py
try:
  yada yada 
except Exception as err:
  ...
```

I have to use MyException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

class MyException(Exception):
"""
Catches the exception raised by MyClass
"""

```
def __init__(self, message):
    self.message = message

def __str__(self):
    return self.message
```

class over():

```
def check(self):
    col1 = 'ageminusone'
    col2 = 'Age'
    col3 = 'Flag'

    data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])


    df[col1] = df.loc[0,col2] - 1

    books = ['romance',  'fiction']

    try:
        regex_pattern = re.compile(r'fiction')
        for book in books:
            match_object = re.search(regex_pattern, booke)
            print(match_object)

    except Exception as err:
        print("There was an error")
        raise MyException("There was an error")
```

obj = over()

obj.check()

output ::

There was an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jthakkar\Downloads\sp\Task\StackOverflow1.py", line 31, in check
match_object = re.search(regex_pattern, booke)
NameError: name 'booke' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jthakkar\Downloads\sp\Task\StackOverflow1.py", line 40, in 
obj.check()
File "C:\Users\jthakkar\Downloads\sp\Task\StackOverflow1.py", line 37, in check
raise MyException("There was an error")
**main**.MyException: There was an error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can this be achieved without using the generic exception class "except Exception as err" ?

Comment: @flying_fluid_four yes, for that your code should throw a custom exception then it will be catch in except block, but your code is not throwing exception of type MyException. try this try:
            regex_pattern = re.compile(r'fiction')
            raise MyException("raising exception")
            # for book in books:
            #     match_object = re.search(regex_pattern, booke)
            #     print(match_object)

        except MyException as err:
            print("There was an error")
            print(err)
            raise MyException("There was an error")

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `except NameError` rather than `except MyException`, since the undefined variable causes a `NameError` to be raised.

To clarify, this:

```py
except MyException:
```

should be

```py
except NameError:
```

This outputs:

```py
There was an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in check
NameError: name 'books' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 17, in check
__main__.MyException
```

Answer (score 0):

I Was able to achieve the desired result by enhancing the custom exception class as follows (as per the accepted answer suggestion):

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

and then completely omitting the additional call in the except statement like so:

```
class over():

    def check():        
        col1 = 'ageminusone'
        col2 = 'Age'
        col3 = 'Flag'

        data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])


        df[col1] = df.loc[0,col2] - 1

        books = ['romance',  'fiction']

        try:
            regex_pattern = re.compile(r'fiction')  
            for book in books:
                match_object = re.search(regex_pattern, booke)
                print(match_object)

        except:
            raise MyException("There was an error")



a = over.check()
print(a)
```

This would give me an error like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare.py", line 48, in check
    match_object = re.search(regex_pattern, booke)
NameError: name 'booke' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare.py", line 59, in <module>
    a = over.check()
  File "compare.py", line 52, in check
    raise MyException("There was an error")
__main__.MyException: There was an error
```